# Running encrypted python code using RSA or AES encryption

Tags: python, encryption, obfuscation

As I was working on a project the topic of code obfuscation came up, as such, would it be possible to encrypt python code using either RSA or AES and then de-code it on the other side and run it?. And if it's possible how would you do it?. I know that you can obfuscate code using Base64, or XOR, but using AES or RSA would be an interesting application. This is simply a generic question for anyone that may have an idea on how to do it. I am just looking to encrypt a piece of code from point A, send it to point B, have it decrypted at point B and run there locally using either AES or RSA. It can be sent by any means, as long as the code itself is encrypted and unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is very possible but would require some setup to work.

First off Base64 is an encoder for encoding data from binary/bytes to a restricted ascii/utf subset for transmission usually over http. Its not really an obfuscator, more like a packager for binary data.

So here is what is needed for this to work.

1. A pre-shared secret key that both point A and point B have. This key cannot be transmitted along with the code since anyone who gets the encrypted code would also get the key to decrypt it.
2. There would need to be an unencrypted code/program that allows you to insert that pre-shared key to use to decrypt the encrypted code that was sent. Can't hardcode the key into the decryptor since again anyone with the decryptor can now decrypt the code and also if the secrey key is leaked you would have to resend out the decryptor to use a different key.
3. Once its decrypted the "decryptor" could save that code to a file for you to run or run the code itself using console commands or if its a python program you can call `eval` or use importlib to import that code and call the function within.
   **WARNING: `eval` is known to be dangerous since it will execute whatever code it reads. If you use `eval` with code you dont trust it can download a virus or grab info from your computer or anything really. DO NOT RUN UNTRUSTED CODE.**

Also there is a difference between AES and RSA. One is a symmetric cipher and the other is asymmetric. Both will work for what you want but they require different things for encryption and decryption. One uses a single key for both while the other uses one for encryption and one for decryption. So something to think about.